# jQuery Fade In and Fade Out Loop back to :first sibling

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

JS Fiddle located here:  http://jsfiddle.net/8nqkA/2/

HTML

```
<div>
<div class="show">Test 1</div>
<div class="hidden">Test 2</div>
<div class="hidden">Test 3</div>
<div class="hidden">Test 4</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunc($(".show"));
});

function myFunc(oEle)
{
       oEle.fadeOut('slow', function(){
            if (oEle.next())
            {
                oEle.next().fadeIn('slow', function(){
                   myFunc(oEle.next());
                });
            }
           else
               oEle.siblings(":first").fadeIn('slow', function(){
               myFunc(oEle.siblings(":first"));
               });
        });
}
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Trying to get it to loop back to Test 1 after it is finished, but doesn't work.  Just want it to start it all over again, what's wrong with this?

Comment: `if (oEle.next())` -- Try checking the `length` property. `if (oEle.next().length)`

Comment: @ahren, I see that your solution works. Why don't you post as an answer?

Comment: @deadlock - I'll do that... but only because the other two answers already posted don't provide anything *useful*. They're just straight "copy this" solutions.

Comment: Ok, waiting on you ahren, and thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (oEle.next()){ // This needs to be oEle.next().length
    oEle.next().fadeIn('slow', function(){
        myFunc(oEle.next());
    });
}else{ // You should wrap this in a block
    oEle.siblings(":first").fadeIn('slow', function(){
        myFunc(oEle.siblings(":first"));
    });
}
```

The reason we test for `.length` is because `.next()` like most jQuery methods, returns jQuery - which can't be tested against directly. You can think of it like an array, so the `.length` property provides us with how many elements are in the currently selection.

We also should wrap your `else` code in a block (`{..}`), because the following code spans more than one line.

Comment: Awesome answer bro!  Thanks for the information on this, definitely makes this answer better quality than the others!

Answer (score 1):

In your code-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunc($(".show"));
});

    function myFunc(oEle)
    {
           oEle.fadeOut('slow', function(){
                if (oEle.next().length)
                {
                    oEle.next().fadeIn('slow', function(){
                       myFunc(oEle.next());
                    });
                }
               else
                   oEle.siblings(":first").fadeIn('slow', function(){
                   myFunc(oEle.siblings(":first"));
                   });
            });
    }
```

Check here for demo-http://jsfiddle.net/8nqkA/3/